# Retrieve lastModifiedByName, lastModifiedDate, etc. from workbench using Apex

Tags: apex

Below is an image highlighting the information that I would like to retrieve programmatically using Apex (would also like to retrieve report last run date). I can see all the relevant information that I need on the workbench, but I want to retrieve that programmatically for select reports and use them in my code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What about soql query like `[SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Id, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name from Report]`?

Comment: @kurunve Yep, that's how you'd do it, and you should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reports are available to be queried via SOQL.
Therefore following query would work:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Id, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Name 
FROM Report
```

More information about available fields can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_report.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But since the ```LastModifiedBy.Name``` only gives the Id, is there any way I can get the name of the user instead of just their Id?

Comment: LastModifiedBy.Name returns name of the user (first name + last name).

Comment: That's odd, because when I run this query I get this ```LastModifiedById=0055f000003C...``` as the result for ```LastModifiedBy.Name``` . I'm only getting the Id and not the first and last name like I should.

Comment: Well, it works fine (https://imgur.com/a/5JnwVzx) . Probably something specific for your query client